# Odbc with php, c#, preg_match is this code possible

Tags: c#, php, odbc, preg-match

I want to know if this is possible.

```
using System;
using System.Data.Odbc;
```

namespace pdw_db
{
    class pdw_db
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length <= 2)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                string alarm_capcode, alarm_text, alarm_korps;

`//kill qoutes in alarmering
            args[1] = args[1].Replace("\"", "");
            args[1] = args[1].Replace("\'", "");
            args[1] = args[1].Replace("'", "");
            args[2] = args[2].Replace("\"", "");
            args[2] = args[2].Replace("\'", "");
            args[2] = args[2].Replace("'", "");

            alarm_capcode = args[0];
            alarm_text = args[1];
            alarm_korps = args[2];

            // alles in de database graag.
            databaseThis(alarm_capcode, alarm_text, alarm_korps);

            string2 = alarm_text;
            preg_match('/(.*\s)([A-Z]+.[0-9]*)(\s.[A-Z]*\s)/', string2, matches);


            preText = matches[1];
            streetName = matches[2];
            postText = matches[4];
            city = matches[3];

            // alles in de database graag.
            databaseThis(streetName, city, preText, postText);
        }
        return;
    }

    static void databaseThis(string capcode, string melding, string korps)
    {
        string queryString = "insert into alarmeringen2012(capcode, melding, label)values(\'" + capcode + "\',\'" + melding + "\',\'" + korps + "\');";
        string queryString = "insert into jos_reports(address, summary, desc)values(\'" + streetName +"\',\'" + preText + "\',\'" + postText + "\');";

        using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection("DSN=pdw_db"))
        {

            OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(queryString, connection);
            connection.Open();
            OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {// do nothing
                Console.WriteLine(reader[0]);
            }
            // Call Close when done reading.

            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}`

}

Example alarm_text string: 
Prio 1 TOM KRANENBURGSTRAAT 140 ENKHUIZEN Buitenbrand ENK646

So the strings are saved at 2 places

Answer (score 0):

The code:

```
preg_match('/(.*\s)([A-Z]+.[0-9]*)(\s.[A-Z]*\s)/', string2, matches);
preText = matches[1];
streetName = matches[2];
postText = matches[4];
city = matches[3];
```

Is similar to this code in C#:

```
// Note: include a reference to System.Text.RegularExpressions.

Match m = Regex.Match(string2, @"(.*\s)([A-Z]+.[0-9]*)(\s.[A-Z]*\s)");

string preText = m.Groups[1].Value;
string streetName = m.Groups[2].Value;
string postText = matches.Groups[4].Value;
string city = matches.Groups[3].Value;
```

(Note that the code will fail: your code shows four capture groups (preText, streetName, postText, and city), but your expression only has three (`(.*\s)`, `([A-Z]+.[0-9]*)`, and `(\s.[A-Z]*\s)`.)

In PHP, `preg_match` will return 1 if the match succeeds and 0 if it fails.  You can query `m.Success` to get the equivalent value (i.e., true if the match succeeds and false if it fails).

The original expression is case-sensitive (e.g., `[A-Z]` will not match lowercase letters.  If you want the search to be case-insensitive, change the line:

```
Match m = Regex.Match(string2, @"(.*\s)([A-Z]+.[0-9]*)(\s.[A-Z]*\s)");
```

to

```
Match m = Regex.Match(string2, @"(.*\s)([A-Z]+.[0-9]*)(\s.[A-Z]*\s)", 
              RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 0):

thnx for your answer.

I will explain what I am doing.

im a firefighter, and im working on a website. that's showing our fire/ems calls.

Prio 1 = urgency  (must be inserted in alerting)

TOM KRANENBURGSTRAAT 140 = street (must be inserted in address)

ENKHUIZEN = city (must be inserted in address)

Buitenbrand = kind of message (must be inserted in data1)

ENK646 = firetruck number (must be inserted in desc)

it will be great to extract those into 5 groups.  but I got it working on four groups. 
street names are always upper case letters

this is my sql:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `brandweer_reports` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data1` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Won',
  `image` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` text NOT NULL,
  `date1` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `date2` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `date3` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `summary` text,
  `boss` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `people` varchar(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `department` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `desc` text,
  `published` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `alerting` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `gmap_report_latitude` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `gmap_report_longitude` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `counter` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `gmap` tinyint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `presse` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `presse2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `presse3` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `updatename` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'admin',
  `updatedate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `boss2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `einsatzticker` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `notrufticker` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `tickerKAT` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `date1` (`date1`),
  KEY `published` (`published`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```